# Nhibernate Exception while flushing session

Tags: nhibernate

I have parent table "Parent" with column "SpokenlanguageId", "WrittenlanguageId". These two columns are referenced by column "languageid" in child table (both Parent table columns are referred by same child table column).

In parent table hbm file, I have included many to one relationship on parent table columns (SpokenlanguageId, WrittenlanguageId) with cascade = "None"
my scenario would be to insert and update data only in parent table not on child table as it a lookup table. I get the following error with above settings being set on my hbm file

NHibernate.TransientObjectException

object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade 
action for the property to something that would make it autosave.

I got above error while flushing the nhibernate session.

Comment: This issue won't be difficult to fix. E.g. correct `unsaved-value` for a class mapping... But, please, provide more details. Mostly **the mapping** and the code representing scenario of assigning the referenced values `SpokenLanguage` and `WrittenLanguage`... *The unsaved value, i.e. ID == 0, seems to me as the most suspected*

Comment: please find my parent table hbm file with properties defined <many-to-one name="SpokLanguages" class="Language" column="SpokenLanguageID" unique="true" cascade="none" />
    <many-to-one name="WrittenLanguages" class="Language" column="WrittenLanguageID" unique="true" cascade="none" />

Comment: To support better formatting, just edit your quesiton. In general, NHibernate is (most likely) telling you: one of the assinged Languages is transient. This is very often caused by the fact, that you did not load it from DB, just assing in C# ... new Language { Name = "English" }. Or if the ID of that loaded instance is equal to NHibernate expected "unsaved value", e.g. 0. Please, show more in your question, with respect to these lines...

Comment: below is the c# code i used to assign the language entity.
i am only assigning LanguageID property because this id only needs to be saved in parent table. and not in lookup table
  SpokLanguages = new Language() {
                    SpokenLanguageID = 5,
                },
                WrittenLanguages = new Language()
                {
                   WrittenLanguageID = 6,
                },

Comment: Parent table properties:
        Language SpokLanguages { get; set; }
        Language WrittenLanguages { get; set; }
  parent.hbm.xml file:
  <many-to-one name="SpokLanguages" class="Language" column="SpokenLanguageID" unique="true" cascade="none" />
  <many-to-one name="WrittenLanguages" class="Language" column="WrittenLanguageID" unique="true" cascade="none" />
  Lkup_language table columns:
   languageID
   languageCd
   languageDesc
child table Properties:
        Int32 Id { get; set; }
        Int32 SpokenLanguageID { get; set; }
        Int32 WrittenLanguageID { get; set; }

Comment: And this would be the issue. I guess that Language has also the ID property. And that must be set to 5 resp 6. This way NHibernate will work properly. E.g.: `new Language() { ID = 6, }`. NHibernate will INSERT into column `WrittenLanguageID` of the Parent table 6. So later, the Language instance loaded, will be with ID 6 representing the Written property. Similar to Spoken. Thee is nothing complicated ;)

Comment: I've tried to summarize that all in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on more information in the comments, there are more details

parent class:

```
Language SpokLanguages { get; set; } 
Language WrittenLanguages { get; set; }
```

parent.hbm.xml file:

```
<many-to-one name="SpokLanguages" class="Language" 
  column="SpokenLanguageID" unique="true" cascade="none" /> 
<many-to-one name="WrittenLanguages" class="Language" 
  column="WrittenLanguageID" unique="true" cascade="none" />
```

And this was the way how to assign property:

```
SpokLanguages    = new Language() { SpokenLanguageID = 5, };
WrittenLanguages = new Language() { WrittenLanguageID = 6, };
```

Which was almost correct, but what we need is to **assign the ID of Language**

```
parent.SpokLanguages    = new Language() { ID = 5, };
parent.WrittenLanguages = new Language() { ID = 6, };
```

because this **ID** property is what is mapped here

the column, in the Paren table will contain the ID of the Language. The essence of the mapping `<many-to-one>` is in fact, that NHibernate is trying to put together the information in the Parent table... with the ID of the Language. The element mapped in Langauge as id

```
<class name="Language" ... 
 <id name="ID"
```

is what we need. If this is missing, entity seems to be transient. And that's why NHibernate blames.

EXTEND:

The more appropriate solution would be to load the instances of selected Languages from DB and assign them. It could be done even with some trick, the Load method. Please, read:

- [NHibernate – The difference between Get, Load and querying by id](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id)

it could look like this

```
parent.SpokLanguages    = session.Load<Language>(5)
parent.WrittenLanguages = session.Load<Language>(6)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Radim.. it worked for me... please suggest any material or sites for learning nHibernate... once again thanks...

Comment: Great if that helped ;) NHibernate is awesome tool, but not sure where to start... I started with docs http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html, then observed the google ;)